# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/raphael/Desktop/RAF/HTML:CSS:JS/PORTFOLIO/build'

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I did everything as said in the github documentation but when I type "npm run deploy" this happens :
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat  Users/raphael/Desktop/RAF/HTML:CSS:JS/PORTFOLIO/build'
at Object.statSync (node:fs:1710:3)
at Object.statSync (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/gh-pages/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:319:16)
at Object.publish (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/gh-pages/lib/index.js:90:13)
at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/gh-pages/bin/gh-pages.js:12:13
at new Promise ()
at publish (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/gh-pages/bin/gh-pages.js:10:10)
at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/gh-pages/bin/gh-pages.js:133:12
and also :
(!) Some chunks are larger than 500 kBs after minification. Consider:

- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
  This is my package.json file :

```
{
  "homepage": "http://Raxuis.github.io/raphael-portfolio/",
  "name": "3dfolio",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
```

This is my vite.config.js file, I tried to add the build part but it doesn't work:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],

  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes("node_modules")) {
            return id
              .toString()
              .split("node_modules/")[1]
              .split("/")[0]
              .toString();
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```